# Get rid of reboot prompt by Software-Updater after e.g. kernel update

Tags: update-manager

I have set the GUI software updater to never automatically check for updates as I prefer doing this myself using the commandline and `apt-get`.

But whenever I install updates that require a reboot (mainly kernel and glibc, I think), still the GUI software updater kicks in and shows me that little reboot prompt with the three buttons <kbd>Settings...</kbd> <kbd>Reboot later</kbd> <kbd>Reboot now</kbd> or similar to this (I'm seeing a translated version of it).

This is annoying, especially as it keeps popping up maybe hourly or so even after I refused to reboot now. I shut the machine down daily anyway and therefore it's not important for me to be reminded of this.

*How do I disable this window from popping up, or how can I configure it to stay closed after I clicked on <kbd>Reboot later</kbd> once?*

---

What I already did is to set the software updater to never automatically look for updates, but this is of course not related to the reboot prompt:

[image: software&updates > update settings]

I also have modified the dconf key `com.ubuntu.update-notifier/no-show-notifications` to `True` using `dconf-editor`, but the window still appears.

[image: dconf-editor]

Answer (score 1):

When you install updates, two files are created in `/run` which are read to determine if updates require rebooting: `reboot-required` and `reboot-required.pkgs`, one of which is just a string indicating a reboot is needed and one which shows which package(s) is calling for it.

You can (as root or with `sudo`) `rm` these two files and that should do it.  Truncating them is not enough - they must not exist.  Curiously, I cannot find anything in the `/etc/apt` files about this and my only real clue came from `/etc/update-motd.d` pointing to `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required` (which is called by SSH on login to indicate a reboot is required), and which has the following code in it:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# helper for update-motd

if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
    cat /var/run/reboot-required
fi
```

`/var/run` is a symlink to `/run`, so there is my answer.  If you don't speak `sh`, the `if [ -f ... ]` is a conditional to see if a file exists; the subsequent cat command prints its contents in the SSH session.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds interesting. I will try it on the next kernel update and report back.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I am impatient so an alternative would be to `touch` both files into existence as root with the default umask, which yields appropriate 644 permissions on them.  Then log out and log back in: behold, the reboot prompt reappears.  Remove them, log out and back in: no prompt.  That was my testing method since kernel updates are not too frequent.

I'll also add the following: since the `if [ -f ___ ]` construct seems to be used and relies on a regular file, I bet if you `touch`ed both files and played with the perms, you could disable the pop-up altogether.

Comment: @ByteCommander: just ran a kernel update and watched the output.  The trigger is  in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` and is a symlink called `update-notifier` to `/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required`, which both touches the files and runs the applet.   You should be able to remove the symlink and then just `touch` an empty file with the same name; an alternative would be the `chmod ugo-x` on the linked file too so that it fails to execute when called.  No more pop-ups.